# Getting values for a common set of dates included in different time series

Tags: time-series

I am working with four different time series which have the same first and last dates, but a different number of observations.  One time series (svq) includes weekend data, the other three don't include weekend data, but seem to be missing a few days each. I can get the Intersection of "Dates" common to all four series and map each index over the common dates to get a matching set of values, but that is perhaps not the best way to get those values.  Can someone suggest a better way?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could use `TimeSeriesResample[{<time series>}, "Intersection"]`

Comment: "doesn't perform as expected is due to poor programming or incomplete understanding of the underlying task" - I get it

Comment: for the record, I wasn't aware you could do *this* with `TimeSeriesResample` until I read this question; that's the reason I like mma.se; it forces you to be honest with what you know and learn the rest

Comment: I didn't really understand the full capabilities of the function. `TimeSeriesResample[ ts , {starttime,endtime,"BusinessDay"}` also worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare and contrast the following example series:

```
ts1 = TimeSeries[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}}]
ts1 // ListLinePlot[#, Mesh -> Full] &
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
ts2 = TimeSeries[{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {{1, 1.3, 2, 3.5, 4}}];
ts2 // ListLinePlot[#, Mesh -> Full] &
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Using

```
TimeSeriesResample[{ts1, ts2}, "Intersection"] // ListLinePlot[#, Mesh -> Full] &
```

we obtain the values at common dates:

[image: Blockquote]